# Transfer the check-out to a different branch

Tags: clearcase

For a feature I have checked out the files on X branch. After some implementation, I realized that I should have branched to Y. I would like to migrate my changes to the correct branch. The only solution which I know is to back-up my changes, undo checkout and branch to Y and restore my changes. 
Is there any other easy way?

Clearcase version is 7.1.1.2 for Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the config spec of your view (in order to make sure any checkout would be done in the new branch)

First undo checkout all your files, with a `-keep` in order to preserve your changes.
Then update the config spec.
That will update your view (reload it if it is a snapshot view), but **won't touch/erase any local modification you currently have** (ie the files you had checked out in the previous branch).
You can then checkout again those files, and check them in.

Comment: "You can then checkout again those files," => I cannot check-out the same file twice from my view, or can I?

Comment: @PermanentGuest you might have to undo checkout them first actually (`unco -keep` in order to preserve your changes)

Answer (score 1):

After creating branch Y, you could always merge directly from X to Y. You might want to have branch Y branch off at the same point as branch X.

You would still have branch X though, you can [delete it though](http://www.philforhumanity.com/ClearCase_Support_49.html).

Should you want to use the back-up-approach, I found WinMerge's folder-compare utility to be fastest. The MergeManager as described above should do the same trick, though.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I would have the permission to delete the branch... I think I would go with the back-up way. Thanks for the tip on the merge.